# Terraform, EKS and cluster-autoscaler

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, eks

I'm trying to deploy cluster-autoscaler to an existing EKS cluster. here's my terraform code:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "cluster_autoscaler" {
  name        = "ClusterAutoscalerPolicy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Policy for allowing the cluster autoscaler to modify cluster resources. Managed by Terraform."
  policy      = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingInstances",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLaunchConfigurations",
        "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
        "autoscaling:DescribeTags",
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceTypes",
        "ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions"
      ],
      "Resource": ["*"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:SetDesiredCapacity",
        "autoscaling:TerminateInstanceInAutoScalingGroup",
        "ec2:DescribeImages",
        "ec2:GetInstanceTypesFromInstanceRequirements",
        "eks:DescribeNodegroup"
      ],
      "Resource": ["*"]
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cluster_autoscaler" {
  name = "EKS-ClusterAutoscaler-Role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Federated = "${var.oidc_prvider_arn}"
        },
        Action = "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        Condition = {
          StringEquals = {
            "${var.oidc_prvider}:sub" : "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler"
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cluster_autoscaler" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.cluster_autoscaler.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.cluster_autoscaler.name

resource "helm_release" "cluster_autoscaler" {
  name       = "cluster-autoscaler"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/autoscaler"
  chart      = "cluster-autoscaler"
  version    = "v9.35.0"
  namespace  = "kube-system"

  set {
    name  = "autoDiscovery.clusterName"
    value = var.cluster_name
  }

  set {
    name  = "awsRegion"
    value = "eu-west-2"
  }

  set {
    name  = "rbac.create"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.create"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.name"
    value = "cluster-autoscaler"
  }

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = var.cluster_autoscaler_role_arn
  }
}
```

I have 2 problems here:

1. cluster-autoscaler seems to ignore set values, for example "describe pod" shows me it's running as an account with a different name in kubernetes -
   Service Account:      cluster-autoscaler-aws-cluster-autoscaler

2.patching it manually and annotating this service account with the role according to https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-load-balancer-webidentityerr makes cluster-autoscaler go into a crashloop with

Failed to regenerate ASG cache: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: AccessDenied: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity^
what am I doing wrong here? Your help would be highly appreciated.
what am I doing wrong here? Your help would be highly appriciated.